# Changing UITextField top inset not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I subclassed a `UITextField`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface TWAdjustmentsTextField : UITextField
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable NSInteger topInset;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable NSInteger leftInset;
@end

#import "TWAdjustmentsTextField.h"

@implementation TWAdjustmentsTextField

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectInset(bounds, self.leftInset, self.topInset);
}
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectInset(bounds, self.leftInset, self.topInset);
}
@end
```

The `leftInset` property seems to work fine, but the `topInset` property seems to have no effect on UITextFields. Is there another way to adjust the top inset of a `UITextField`?

Comment: I'm wondering whether you should adjust the font size.

Comment: @Lumialxk font size won't help with my problem. My problem is that I need to offset the text inside the UITextField so that it's slightly more aligned towards the bottom edge of the UITextField

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, CGRectMake can solve the problem :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface TWAdjustmentsTextField : UITextField
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable NSInteger topInset;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable NSInteger leftInset;
@end

#import "TWAdjustmentsTextField.h"

@implementation TWAdjustmentsTextField

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + leftInset, bounds.origin.y + topInset, bounds.size.width - leftInset * 2, bounds.size.height - topInset * 2);
}
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee of any negative side effects, but this seems to work with what I'm trying to do.

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGRect rect = bounds;
    rect.origin.x += self.leftInset;
    rect.origin.y += self.topInset;
    return rect;
}
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGRect rect = bounds;
    rect.origin.x += self.leftInset;
    rect.origin.y += self.topInset;
    return rect;

}
- (CGRect)placeholderRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGRect rect = bounds;
    rect.origin.x += self.leftInset;
    rect.origin.y += self.topInset;
    return rect;
}
```